# Can I free (or reuse) a string after passing to `sqlite3_bind_text`, `sqlite3_step`, `sqlite3_reset`?

Tags: sqlite

I have a string buffer which I am re-using for multiple queries. I want to:

1. allocate the string
2. pass to `sqlite3_bind_text`
3. execute the statement with `sqlite3_step`
4. reset the statement with `sqlite3_reset`
5. goto 2

I think I should be OK, but can someone confirm that SQLite doesn't require a pointer to the string after this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bindings are not cleared by the `sqlite3_reset()` routine. See the [SQLite bindings documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) for details. The binding woud be re-used if the statement is stepped again.

You could make a case that freeing the string would be safe as long as the statement has the parameter bound once again before it is stepped. To be safe, you could bind the parameter to a static string before freeing the allocated string.

Addendum based on comments below, and refined requirements:

If you want to reuse the buffer rather than free it, the safest method is to modify the buffer after sqlite_reset and then call sqlite3_bind_text with the modified buffer before the next sqlite3_step. In this case, [use `SQLITE_STATIC` as the binding type](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/c_static.html) (fifth argument to `sqlite3_bind_text`).

Using `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` forces sqlite to copy the string; with that option you can reuse the buffer right after the call to `sqlite3_bind_text`. In this case that isn't necessary; using `SQLITE_STATIC` will be more efficient by eliminating memory allocations.

Comment: My case is that I am using a single string buffer (to iterate over something) and make an insert for each loop. Would this work? It seems to work, but I don't know if that's defined behaviour or not.

Comment: It would be safest to modify the buffer after `sqlite_reset` and then call `sqlite3_bind_text` with the modified buffer before the next `sqlite3_step`.

Comment: I'm calling `reset` at the end of my loop and modifying it at the start (as per my question) so unless I misunderstood you, yes that's happening.

Comment: That will be safe, then. Use SQLITE_STATIC as the binding type (fifth argument to sqlite3_bind_text): http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_static.html

Comment: Thanks, but by my reading of that SQLITE_TRANSIENT would be a better choice given that I'm about to change the contents of the buffer.

Comment: Using `SQLITE_TRANSIENT` forces sqlite to copy the string; with that option you can reuse the buffer right after the call to `sqlite3_bind_text`. In your case this isn't necessary; using `SQLITE_STATIC` will be more efficient by eliminating memory allocations.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll accept your answer but if you could add your elaborations to it that would be great.